# Treat NSString as an array pointer arithmetic

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsstring

Is there any way to treat `NSString` as an array like you can with `C` strings to use pointer arithmetic to loop through an `NSString`? I am trying to do a simple `strstr` without using built in `Objective C` methods so I need a `C` style array to loop through. If there's a better data structure that I can use, let me know.

Comment: @"somestring".UTF8String ... then fiddle with it (and by fiddle with it I meant read it, don't write to the internal memory)

Comment: better use `-getBytes:maxLength:enocding:`which creates a copy with defined lifetime. However, what for? If looping with `-characterAtIndex:` is a performance issue, one should try `IMP` first.

Comment: You should update your question with a clear example of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can access the c string array like

```
NSString *string = @"string";

for (NSInteger i=0; i<string.length; i++) {
    printf("%c\n",string.UTF8String[i]);
    // or
    printf("%c\n",[string characterAtIndex:i]);
}
```

the output will look like this

```
s
s
t
t
r
r
i
i
n
n
g
g
```

Answer (score 0):

See the [`[NSString characterAtIndex:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/characterAtIndex:) method to access a character at a particular index, just like `[NSArray objectAtIndex:]`:

```
NSString *test = @"Hello World";
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < test.length; i++)
    unichar c = [test characterAtIndex:i];
```